# Can I convert a stereo receiver's hard-wired two-prong power cord to an IEC C7?

Tags: power-connector, iec

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZfnf.jpg)enter image description here[image]

[image]

Repairs to my stereo receiver require considerable disassembly.
One step requires me to unsolder the two mains leads from posts on the main circuit board.
(the polarized, two-prong plug, AC cord enters through a strain relief bushing on the back panel.)

I'd like to change this setup to an IEC receptacle (C7, polarized), but I'm hesitant since everything I've read says they are for low-power home appliances.

Is such a setup OK to use on my late '80s, 80 W per channel receiver?

Comment: It's physically possible. How much power does the receiver consume, though? Amplifiers are what takes a lot of power. Or is it a combo receiver/amplifier unit?

Comment: Does the current cable have any printing on it? Or the flat plastic side of the plug? We're looking for a maximum amperage.

Comment: That depends on what is the device power/current rating at your rated voltage. It is printed on the device. Sometimes C7/C8 is rated for higher currents so you must know what are the ratings of the connector you will buy and if that rating applies to your local electrical codes. Also the polarized C7/C8 is not an IEC standard, and it is dangerous as you can connect a non-polarized cable to polarized inlet. So technically, nothing stops you, but I don't think you should unless you know that what you are doing is safe, legal and up to electrical code.

Comment: check the writings on the back plate for how much AC current the stereo uses.

Comment: In answer to the response above, I have added images to the original post

Comment: @Justme - not sure I understand - I have found many references to IEC 320 C7 (Polarized) - is that not an IEC standard?

Comment: @DrSmokeWrench nope, it's a proprietary abomination of C7 :D

Comment: @DrSmokeWrench what's the "grid-side" plug on your cable?

Comment: @Marcus Müller - if I understand your question correctly, it's a polarized, 2 prong plug

Comment: @DrSmokeWrench that you said :-) ! I don't know whether you're referring to a British, Russian, French, Japanese, South American or North American one :) What I do know is that it's probably not a German one – there's no polarized two-connector connectors in German residential electrical installation. So, can you pick yours from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets please?

Comment: @DrSmokeWrench OK, so just to be sure, you have the 120V or 220V version of the amp? And seriously, no current rating listed on the amp itself? The manual is not very helpful, but if the amp has outlets they must be added to calculations. Assuming 120V, the 250 watts rating is awfully close to max rating of 2.5 A for C7/C8. And no, a polarized version of of the IEC C7/C8 is not in any IEC standard. Do we have to assume you live in North America, have 120V 60 Hz mains and  polarized NEMA 1-15P plug?

Comment: @Marcus Müller - from the Wiki page I have a polarized plug NEMA 1-15 ungrounded (Type A)

Comment: @Justme - sincere apologies for my lack of world view. I live in North America and have the 120V version. I will endeavor to dig the unit out and get back tag info.

Comment: @DrSmokeWrench ah cool, gotta change my answer :)

Comment: the part under consideration:  https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/tensility-international-corp/11-00012/3900569

Comment: `One step requires me to unsolder the two mains leads from posts on the main circuit board.` ... are you certain  that is required? ... please add a picture of the strain relief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is more detective work than it's actually worth, but let's give it a shot:

- We're dealing with a US-American appliance, so 120V

  - The power cord looks bifurcated – which would be very untypical for the European market for the late 80s/very early 90s (which is the era that the manual's font suggests)
- This is a Sony device

  - because it recommends Sony batteries and a sony-specific remote control family
- This cable carries up to 10A, and one *really* has to dimension for that continuous current

  - the manual says "2 switchable AC outlets", so no matter how low the power consumption of the receiver itself is, we cannot risk it starting a fire later on
  - the cable says "AWG18", also suggesting the 10A are expected
  - at 120V, the rated 150 W power (however you end up with a 2×80W output rating with less than 160W input rating… marketing) would be only a bit above 1A, but the fact that there's additional outlets really is the game changer here: saving money on the supply plug might start a fire later on.

My best bet is this is the Sony STR-GX 5 ES, as that has the right amplifier output power claim, and was manufactured 1988–1989.

That all in all says that you can do this with a plug/cable combination actually rated for 10A – but as others have said, the IEC C7 is officially only rated for 2.5 A, and the polarized version of it is proprietary. So you need to check with the vendor of said plug, **and** said cable, that you actually get something tested and rated for 10 A. That has downsides: you or someone else might later on just use a cheaper cable, which then could potentially pretty hot.

I'm by no means an expert in North American appliances, so, I don't know whether there's feasible alternatives to a polarized modification of IEC C7; if you can, I'd try to get IEC C17/C18 – but I'll be honest, as a European I can remember but a single device in my whole life that had that plug.  C18 has the advantage that you can plug in the very ubiquitous C13 cable.

Comment: thank you so much for that detailed answer -- It is indeed am STR-GX5ES - somewhere up above (not used to this format) I put in a link to the proposed part.

Comment: ah, just found the link – nah, that's only rated for 7A.

Comment: See the edit in my answer's last paragraph.

Comment: The page says 7A -- that's a digi-key typo -- Tensility's PDF datasheet says "10A at 125 VAC"

Comment: Just read your last para. -- do I just not hookup the ground prong?

Comment: no, C18 is a receptable that doesn't *have* that ground prong – it'd be lying to install C14 (which has), as then anyone looking at the device will think it's a class I grounded device. Which they really shouldn't. But you can still use the C13 plug (which doesn't have the ground inverse-prong) in a C18 receptable :)

Comment: Marcus - Thank you so much for your time and assistance

Comment: @MarcusMüller I believe it might be worth emphasizing that if a polarized plug is required for safety, then C8 inlet is dangerous, as anyone can just plug in an unpolarized C7 plug to polarized C8 inlet. So the problem is not just limited to someone using a C7 plug or accompanying wires that not rated for enough current.

Comment: @Justme wait, you can plug an unpolarized plug into an unpolarized receptable?! who came up with… sigh.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think we can guess who came up with that - And the funny part is, a clause was added to the IEC 60320-1:2015 standard, that it must not be possible for a non-standard connector to couple with a standard connector. That should teach 'em!

Answer (score 1):

I will add my own answer for completeness sake.

The amplifier is an US model. It has an ungrounded polarized plug, and according to the schematics, it has polarized ungrounded outlets for other devices and a leakage resistor between Neutral and the ungrounded metal chassis.

Therefore preserving the polarity of Live and Neutral is very important, so unpolarized mains couplers are out of the question.

The polarized C7/C8 couplers are non-standard, and the polarization may not be standardized, and the polarized inlet on a device accepts a non-polarized coupler, it will not preserve the polarity if someone uses a wrong unpolarized cable.

Therefore, it will be unsafe to change a fixed polarized mains cord to C7/C8 couplers, even polarized ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One of the pins is identified probably wider. use your ohm meter and determine which terminal it is soldered to. When you install the new cord do the same thing in reverse. If the existing  cord does not have any polarization on the plug just connect it.

Comment: -Appreciate that installation advice, but my question regards power handling capability of this connection system (IEC C7) vis a vis power requirements of receiver.

Answer (score 0):

IEC C7 handles something like 2.5A at 220V or 10A at 120V. This should be enough for everybody(c).

In 120V world, 10A amount to 1200W total power.

The "150W power consumption" tag hints that you are well within the 1200W limit and also hints that it is not exactly 2x80W either.

In 230V world, 2.5A will get you somewhat below 600W - still more than enough for your 150W needs.

Comment: err, IEC C7 handles 2.5 A.

Comment: Even 2.5A @ 110V will be enough. But as far as I remember, those 110-120V people abuse C7 all the way to 10A

Comment: @MarcusMüller True, but for some bizarre reason, North American rating agencies can certify the IEC C7/C8 comnectors to 10A. Now, obviously, it needs to be a connetor that has passed the testing and have the UL ir CSA marks on it, otherwise it cannot be used at 10 A.

Comment: @Justme How does one enter emojis on a desktop keyboard… 

Comment: @MarcusMüller I dunno :) But I guess they just need more current due to lower voltage, so it might be fine to take an existing connector standard, and make sure their versions are made to handle 10A. I mean, they made the polarized version of standard IEC C7/C8 too.